# Popup Not Center of Screen - CSS Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I've adapted some code that I have sourced which shows a popup after X seconds. The JavaScript functionality seems fine, the issue is that whatever I try I am unable to center the popup in the middle of the screen.

Please see the popup here:

http://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/

I have tried wrapping the popup in another `div`, setting that `div` to `width: 100%` and`position: fixed` then setting the popup container to `margin: 0 auto`, without success.

I have also tried various `display` and `position` properties. What I understand is that the popup container doesn't have anything to be the center of, which is why I tried to wrap it inside another `div` but I'm unable to make this work as I wish.

Please see my code below:

**CSS:**

```
#wd1_nlpopup {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    top: 200px !important;
    padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wd1_nlpopup_close {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#wd1_nlpopup_close:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="wd1_nlpopup" data-expires="30" data-delay="1">
    <a href="#closepopup" id="wd1_nlpopup_close">X</a>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://form.jotformeu.com/jsform/62332622875356"></script>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
    var wd1_nlpopup_expires = jQuery("#wd1_nlpopup").data("expires");
    var wd1_nlpopup_delay = jQuery("#wd1_nlpopup").data("delay") * 1000;

    jQuery('#wd1_nlpopup_close').on('click', function(e){
        jQuery.cookie('wd1_nlpopup', 'closed', { expires: wd1_nlpopup_expires, path: '/' });
        jQuery('#wd1_nlpopup,#wd1_nlpopup_overlay').fadeOut(200);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    if(jQuery.cookie('wd1_nlpopup') != 'closed' ){
        setTimeout(wd1_open_nlpopup, wd1_nlpopup_delay);
    }

    function wd1_open_nlpopup(){
        var topoffset = jQuery(document).scrollTop(),
            viewportHeight = jQuery(window).height(),
            jQuerypopup = jQuery('#wd1_nlpopup');
        var calculatedOffset = (topoffset + (Math.round(viewportHeight/2))) - (Math.round(jQuerypopup.outerHeight()/2));

        if(calculatedOffset <= 40){
            calculatedOffset = 40;
        }

        jQuerypopup.css('top', calculatedOffset);
        jQuery('#wd1_nlpopup,#wd1_nlpopup_overlay').fadeIn(500);
    }

});



/* jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.3.1 */
(function(a){if(typeof define==="function"&&define.amd){define(["jquery"],a);}else{a(jQuery);}}(function(e){var a=/\+/g;function d(g){return g;}function b(g){return decodeURIComponent(g.replace(a," "));}function f(g){if(g.indexOf('"')===0){g=g.slice(1,-1).replace(/\\"/g,'"').replace(/\\\\/g,"\\");}try{return c.json?JSON.parse(g):g;}catch(h){}}var c=e.cookie=function(p,o,u){if(o!==undefined){u=e.extend({},c.defaults,u);if(typeof u.expires==="number"){var q=u.expires,s=u.expires=new Date();s.setDate(s.getDate()+q);}o=c.json?JSON.stringify(o):String(o);return(document.cookie=[c.raw?p:encodeURIComponent(p),"=",c.raw?o:encodeURIComponent(o),u.expires?"; expires="+u.expires.toUTCString():"",u.path?"; path="+u.path:"",u.domain?"; domain="+u.domain:"",u.secure?"; secure":""].join(""));}var g=c.raw?d:b;var r=document.cookie.split("; ");var v=p?undefined:{};for(var n=0,k=r.length;n<k;n++){var m=r[n].split("=");var h=g(m.shift());var j=g(m.join("="));if(p&&p===h){v=f(j);break;}if(!p){v[h]=f(j);}}return v;};c.defaults={};e.removeCookie=function(h,g){if(e.cookie(h)!==undefined){e.cookie(h,"",e.extend(g,{expires:-1}));return true;}return false;};}));
```

Would anybody please be able to advise on where I'm going wrong with my CSS? Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Basic problem is that you can't use margin:0 auto; to center absolutely positioned element. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css to your `#wd1_nlpopup`

```
{
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 600px; // add a size for your modal
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

The final css:

```
#wd1_nlpopup {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 600px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wd1_nlpopup_close {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#wd1_nlpopup_close:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mohammad, the central position worked perfectly but for some reason the popup then sticks to the top of the page. Could you advise why this may be happening? Thank you. http://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/

Comment: @matt136 Do you want to make it fixed on scroll?

Comment: Sorry, when I looked before it was broken (at the very top of the screen), I'll take a look into this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
wd1_nlpopup {
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By just a quick lookup !! try the below css. Change this to your css, hope it helps

```
#wd1_nlpopup {        
    margin: 10% 38% !important;
    top: 0px !important;}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Nalin, but unfortunately this isn't exactly central. Also if it's loaded on a tablet device, the popup is to the far-right.